# Login & Session not working on localhost using codeigniter & Ion_Auth

Tags: codeigniter, session, authentication, ion-auth

I have a live site which works fine and can be logged into no problems. I have a local copy of that site but for some reason the session isn't working. If i login, i can tell that the login has worked as it tries to redirect to the success page and i can see that a new session gets started.

But, the system doesn't recognise me as being logged in.

I've changed the cookie_domain config variable, changed session_ip and session_user_agent matching variables but nothing seems to work.

Also, i increased the size of the fields that hold session/userdata data in the db to longtext to make sure nothing was being chopped off.

Is there anything i've missed, anything that i've forgotten?

Comment: have you checked your sessions expiration valu ein config.php ..`$config['sess_expiration'] = 'somevalue'`.

Comment: Well, yes, but it works on the live site, so why wouldn't it work on the local one with the same setting?

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh, my bad. I didn't realise i had a dev only config in there that needed to have it's cookie domain changed. Whoops!!